# Exact sequences and derived functors

Tags: homological-algebra

> Let  $R$   be  a  commutative  ring and  $  r\in R$.  Denote $R_r = \{ s\in R \mid s  r =0 \}$.  If $R_r $  is   nonzero 
>   $0 \rightarrow R_r  \rightarrow R\stackrel{r\cdot} \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/ rR \rightarrow 0$   is  exact.
>    Deduce  that $$ 0 \rightarrow  \mathrm{Tor}_2^R( R/ rR, M)  \rightarrow  R_r 
>  \otimes_RM \rightarrow M \rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}_1^R( R/ rR, M)   $$
>   is exact   as  well and  the  most  right arrow   is   surjective.

I  try  to  apply  the  long   exact  sequence  of $\mathrm{Tor}$.  I  deduce  just  that $\mathrm{Tor}_2^R( R/ rR, M)$  is  isomorphic to $\mathrm{Tor}_1^R( R_r, M)$  but   I  think  this  is  not  useful. Can  you   give  me  a  hint?

Comment: Maybe try to deduce from your exact sequence two short exact sequences, and consider the two homology long exact sequences.

Comment: @Bernard Thank  you! I   will  try!

Comment: @Bernard I   proved  the   exactness excepting   the   last  arrow.  Can  you   give  me   concrete idea   because I  tried all   the possibilities......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence you give is not exact. To see this you can take $M=R$. So the last term must be $rR\otimes_RM$.

I think if $M$ is good enough satisfying some property you can get this sequence.